# HandsOnTable Paint Modified Rows in Different Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, user-controls, handsontable

I want to highlight modified rows in [HandsOnTable](https://github.com/handsontable/jquery-handsontable).

I keep a non-visible column named "ismodified" that is initially set to false, and is set to true whenever the row is modified, and I created a renderer function:

```
function modifiedRowRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    if (instance.getData()[row].ismodified)
        $(td).addClass('row-modified');
}
```

I have a settings object that contains the data and other options passed to the Handsontable plugin, so I hook up the renderer like so:

```
settings = { ... }

settings.cells = function(row, col, prop) {
    var cellProperties = {};
    cellProperties.renderer = modifiedRowRenderer;
    return cellProperties;
}

$(container).handsontable(settings);
```

The problem is that it is extremely slow, to the point of being unusable.

### Edit:

In the afterChange event handler I have a line that updates the ismodified property, like so:

```
this.setDataAtRowProp(row, 'ismodified', true);
```

It looks like that is the offending line which causes the widget to crash, because the setDataAtRowProp() seems to trigger a renderer call.  Changing it to:

```
if (!this.getDataAtRowProp(row, 'ismodified'))
    this.setDataAtRowProp(row, 'ismodified', true);
```

helps, but there has to be a better way.

How can I achieve this without hindering performance?

TIA,

Igal

Comment: Can you share fiddle of this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500164/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-changed-cell-in-handsontable ?