# highlight the row if a cell is edited in Rhandsontable and keep track of all changes

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I'm developing a shiny app which is reading data from SQL database and present it in a rhandsontable and allows user to edit the data. I would like to add some functionality before I submit the changes back to the database :

1. How could I highlight a row in rhandsontable if a cell in that
   row was edited ?
2. Is there a way to collect all the changes / edits on the table,
   since the `input$myTable$changes$changes` just shows the last
   changes !

here is my minimal sample code:

```
df <- structure(list(NumberOfWEC = c(3, 4, 54, 19, 10, 6, 8, 11, 140, 
                               11, 34), Source = c("SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "RBP", 
                                                   "SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "SRP"), Status = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                                                            3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CANDIDATE", 
                                                                                                                                                                "APPROVED", "EXISTING"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         11L), class = "data.frame")



ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ColNames <- (colnames(df))
  ColNames <- ColNames[!ColNames %in% "Status"]
  
  
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df) %>% hot_col(ColNames, readOnly = TRUE)})
  
  observeEvent(input$myTable$changes$changes, {

    changedRow = 1 + as.numeric(input$myTable$changes$changes[[1]][[1]])
    changedColl = 1 + as.numeric(input$myTable$changes$changes[[1]][[2]])
    OldValue = input$myTable$changes$changes[[1]][[3]]
    NewValue = input$myTable$changes$changes[[1]][[4]]
    print(paste0("changedRow = ",changedRow, " changedColl = ", changedColl, " OldValue = ", OldValue, " NewValue = ", NewValue, " by = ",session$user))
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem by myself and found some time ago the solution here [Change cell background of rHandsontable with afterChange event on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718129/change-cell-background-of-rhandsontable-with-afterchange-event-on-client-side)
So the provided code is not generated by myself:

The main changes to your code:

1. add the `change_hook` function at the top.
2. this code in the server part:

```
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({rht = rhandsontable(df) %>% hot_col(ColNames, readOnly = TRUE)
  htmlwidgets::onRender(rht,change_hook)
  })
```

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

change_hook <- "function(el,x) {
var hot = this.hot;  
var cellChanges = [];

var changefn = function(changes,source) { 
if (source === 'edit' || source === 'undo' || source === 'autofill' || source === 'paste') {
row = changes[0][0];
col = changes[0][1];
oldval = changes[0][2];
newval = changes[0][3];

if (oldval !== newval) {
  var cell = hot.getCell(row, col);
  cell.style.background = 'pink';
  cellChanges.push({'rowid':row, 'colid':col});
}
}
}

var renderfn = function(isForced) {

for(i = 0; i < cellChanges.length; i++)
{

var rowIndex = cellChanges[i]['rowid'];
var columnIndex = cellChanges[i]['colid'];

var cell = hot.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex);
cell.style.background = 'yellow';

}


}

var loadfn = function(initialLoad) {

for(i = 0; i < cellChanges.length; i++)
    {
      var rowIndex = cellChanges[i]['rowid'];
      var columnIndex = cellChanges[i]['colid'];

      var cell = hot.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex);

      cell.style.background = 'white';

    }
cellChanges = []

}


hot.addHook('afterChange', changefn);
hot.addHook('afterRender', renderfn);
hot.addHook('afterLoadData', loadfn);


}"

df <- structure(list(NumberOfWEC = c(3, 4, 54, 19, 10, 6, 8, 11, 140, 
11, 34), Source = c("SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "RBP", 
"SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "SRP", "SRP"), Status = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CANDIDATE", 
"APPROVED", "EXISTING"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
11L), class = "data.frame")



ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ColNames <- (colnames(df))
  ColNames <- ColNames[!ColNames %in% "Status"]
  
  
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({rht = rhandsontable(df) %>% hot_col(ColNames, readOnly = TRUE)
  htmlwidgets::onRender(rht,change_hook)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$myTable$changes$changes, {
    
    changedRow = 1 + as.numeric(input$myTable$changes$changes[[1]][[1]])
    changedColl = 1 + as.numeric(input$myTable$changes$changes[[1]][[2]])
    OldValue = input$myTable$changes$changes[[1]][[3]]
    NewValue = input$myTable$changes$changes[[1]][[4]]
    print(paste0("changedRow = ",changedRow, " changedColl = ", changedColl, " OldValue = ", OldValue, " NewValue = ", NewValue, " by = ",session$user))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for providing the answer. Do you have any idea about second part of the question: how to save cell editing if user make more than one edit ? With input $mytable$changes$changes we have just the last edit